# How to cast a javax.faces.model.ResultSetDataModel$ResultSetMap to java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, jsf, resultset

I am currently developing a web application using JSF. When I try to insert a hashmap from the datatable, it gives me an error, however it works when inserting a object into my function. I then try to cast this object into a hashmap, which gives the error.

Here is my method:

```java
    public void addCart(Object product) {
        System.out.println("This is a test: " + product);
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) product;
        System.out.println("This is a test: " + map.entrySet());
    }
```

Here is the datatable code:

```xml
            <h:form>
                <h:dataTable value="#{storeInfo.info}" var="p" summary="Product list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px" class="tablef table container">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Product name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.itemName}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Product Description"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.itemDesc}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Product Price"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.price}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Add To Cart"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandButton action="#{storeInfo.addCart(p)}" value="Add Item"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

The data being passed into the datatable is in a resultset.

I have tried different paramater types, the only one that has worked is an object, which im not sure how to then use in order to access the key:values.

I expected it to take the information and then print it to console.

The result is similar to the error that is displayed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [Javadoc of `javax.faces.model.ResultSetDataModel`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/model/resultdatamodel):

> public class ResultDataModel extends DataModel<SortedMap<String,Object>>

So it is a datamodel for `SortedMap<String, Object>`.

When we drill down into the [Javadoc for `java.util.SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), then we see this:

> **All Superinterfaces:**
> Map<K,V>

It does thus absolutely not extend from [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). That would only give you a `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Just use `SortedMap` or `Map` instead:

```java
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) product;
```

Or, better, declare the argument type as-is so that you don't need an additional line to cast:

```java
public void addCart(Map<String, String> product) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It solved my problem! I appreciate it.